# No Manifest Detected, Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error. React.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

Suddenly I have got stuck on this problem all my screen is blank and white. I did attach all the necessary files and pic there.
probably manisfest.json and indext.html can not link properly but both are in a same directory and you can see I did link tag in indext.html properly.

one thing also I find in console which is

```
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

I actually did not able to understand which this error exactly

I have another project on react, while I go to open this project locally everything is fine.

If anyone here faced earlier to this problem and have proper solution, requesting to help me.

this is manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

this is indext.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon1.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/Title_Image.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <!-- <link rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.webmanifest" /> -->
    <!-- <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest"/> -->
    <!-- <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials"> -->

    **<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />**
    
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />

    <title>React</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
 
  </body>

</html>
```

This is my file structure..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z6G3.png)

This is the console tab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCV4U.png)

This application tab on chrome devTool

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYOl3.png)

This is Audit/ Lighthouse tab report on devTool of chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kanVu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oebLd.png)

Comment: Remove `**<link rel="manifest" hre="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />**` and check pls

Comment: Not worked, I tried it one more times

Comment: Most probably it is an issue with the syntax in one of your component, or you are trying to load a invalid json using import. Without looking into your code it is difficult to answer.